# Gradle run only one test suite

Tags: java, junit, gradle

I have multiple classes under tests using junit and gradle. When I run "gradle test", all my classes are tested. How can I run just one test file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can run a single test file from the cli like this:

```
gradle test --tests org.gradle.SomeTest
```

You can also run just a particular test method in a similar way:

```
gradle test --tests org.gradle.SomeTest.someSpecificFeature
```

Comment: Just learned this today, and I think it's terrible. Who has time to accurately type all that crap? I'm used to being able to click a single button in Netbeans and *it just works*...

Comment: If you are using some ide, for example IDEA, it can usually handle gradle pretty well, so you can run the test from IDE with one click in place of the gradle commands. Unless you are debugging some gradle-related issues which appear in the test, that is usually just fine.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `test.single` system property. Have a look at [this](https://dzone.com/articles/gradle-goodness-running-single) article.