# Gradle separate test classpath dependencies for scala and java tests

Tags: java, scala, gradle, mockito

I use Mockito in my Java tests, and have some Scala tests. If I include Scala testCompile dependency then Mockito fail to create a spy when running in IntelliJ, and I get ClassCastException exception.

Can I separate the scala and the java tests, so the java tests have some dependencies and the scala has other dependencies?

Comment: Turns out it was IntelliJ that messed up, not Scala, Gradle or Mockito, it runs when running direcltly in Gradle . I think this mention my issue:  https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000191604-Unit-Tests-run-from-Gradle-and-IDEA-differ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have to run all your tests in the same build, you can use dependency profiles. Lets say `scalaTests` and `javaTests`.
And you can group test dependencies like below

```
dependencies {
    ....
    if (project.hasProperty('scalaTests')) {
        //scala test dependencies here
    }
    else if (project.hasProperty('javaTests'))
       //java test dependencies here
    }
 }
```

You also have to run only Scala tests when you are using Scala profile(same for java test)
You can run gradle with scalaTests profile like this `gradle -PscalaTests ..` (same for java case)

For running specific tests

[How to run only one test class on gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505533/how-to-run-only-one-test-class-on-gradle)

[Gradle run only one test suite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31344419/gradle-run-only-one-test-suite)

For profile details.

https://gist.github.com/szpak/1499336

[Maven profiles equivalent of Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659986/maven-profiles-equivalent-of-gradle)

Comment: Thank you, this helped me, I didn't realize I could use if in dependencies.